# View directory that I created for my application on android

Tags: android, local-storage

I create a directory using `new File(mContext.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), "my_stuff")`. I then put some files in it. Is there a way to view the content of that directory either through terminal using `adb` command or through eclipse? I am running app on a device while testing. By content I mean the name of the files that I added; and then if they are empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with few different options, but if you just want to dump to the console try:

```
cat you_file.txt
```

Comment: Why would this work from the terminal? The file is saved to my device.  When I print the path I see "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.app/files/icons/my_img.png"